# ReactiveCocoa swift3 migration

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa-3

I am translating a piece of code from swift2 to swift 3.
I am using ReactiveCocoa and my old code is this :

```
API.signin(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
    .on(started: {
            SVProgressHUD.show()
        },
        failed: { [weak self] error in
            if error == .NotAuthorized {
                self?.view.window?.dodo.error("Not authorized")
            } else {
                self?.view.window?.dodo.error("An error occured !")
            }
        },
        terminated: {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        },
        next: { [weak self] user in
            print("user: \(user)")
            UserService.userId = user.identifier

            self?.emailTextField.text = nil
            self?.passwordTextField.text = nil
            self?.performSegueWithIdentifier(kRootSegueIdentifier, sender: self)
        })
    .start()
```

}

API.signin is of type SignamProducer
It seems the "next:" is no longer here in the new version of ReactiveCoca. What shall I do ?

Answer (score 0):

now it becomes value: like below

```
SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value: 1)
        .on(value: {
            print("value = \($0)")
        })
        .start()
```

Comment: Thks. So you no longer have Next: It has been replaced by value: